# How to batch insert lots of rows using Enterprise Library DAAB?

Tags: c#, insert, enterprise-library, daab, batch-insert

How can I execute 1000s of INSERT queries using Enterprise Library DAAB? That is to say how can I insert lots of rows into a table using DAAB all at once efficiently? And without using a for-loop. Thanks.

Comment: I updated my answer. You can use ODP.NET.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, I'm not sure you can do that using the Enterprise Library DAAB without extending it. As an alternative you can use SqlBulkCopy.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlbulkcopy.aspx

**EDIT**

The [Oracle Data Provider for .NET (ODP.NET)](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/dotnet/index-085163.html) supports this via the Array Binding feature.

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/issue-archive/2009/09-sep/o59odpnet-085168.html

Comment: I'm using an Oracle database. Can't use SqlBulkCopy.

Comment: I would say the OracleDataAdapter(), but that is now obsolete.